# Instrução update SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, delphi

Bom dia. Tenho a seguinte SQL rodando:

```
UPDATE pessoas SET implante = true FROM saida WHERE saida.prontuario = pessoas.prontuario
and saida.mes LIKE (date_part('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) || '%')
```

Na tabela `pessoas` estão todos os registros. Na tabela `saida` estão somente os registros previamente incluídos. Assim, na tabela `saida` não existem todas as `pessoas`. É possível que ao executar a SQL acima, além de registrar o campo `implante` como true conforme a instrução, também registrar como false o restante dos registros do campo `implante` da tabela `pessoas`?

Comment: Meio estranha esta sua condição `saida.mes LIKE (date_part('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) || '%')`. Você não informou qual o tipo de dado de `sida.mes` mas será que não bastaria uma comparação por igualdade sem o uso de `LIKE`? O retorno da função `date_part` é um double e aí concatena com '%', aparentemente complicações desnecessárias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom dia Jones, para usar uma mesma instrução que faça as duas funções que você precisa e como ensinado pelo Heitor, basta fazer a junção dos dois códigos passados por ele, por exemplo:

```
UPDATE pessoas 
SET implante = true 
WHERE pessoas.prontuario IN (SELECT saida.prontuario
                         FROM saida 
                         WHERE saida.mes LIKE (date_part('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) || 
'%'))

IF(@@ERROR = 0)
BEGIN

UPDATE pessoas 
SET implante = false 
WHERE pessoas.prontuario NOT IN (SELECT saida.prontuario
                         FROM saida 
                         WHERE saida.mes LIKE (date_part('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) || 
'%'))

END
```

Explicação do código acima: Executo o update(true) para todas pessoas que constam na tabela de saída e caso não tem erro nessa execução, eu executo o update (false) para todas as pessoas que não estão cadastradas na tabela de saída.

Answer (score -1):

Para fazer um **UPDATE** na coluna **IMPLANTE** da tabela **PESSOAS**, com a condicional do **MES** da tabela **SAIDA**, você precisa realizar um **UPDATE** com a condicional **IN**:

```
UPDATE pessoas 
SET implante = true 
WHERE pessoas.prontuario IN (SELECT saida.prontuario
                             FROM saida 
                             WHERE saida.mes LIKE (date_part('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) || '%'))
```

Instrução do comando:

Faça um update na tabela pessoas informando que implante é igual a true, onde for encontrado o numero de prontuário dentro da condicional in.

Condicional in busca os números dos prontuários na tabela saida que entram dentro da condicional estabelecida no where.

Para realizar o **UPDATE** com o **FALSE** os que não estão na condição do where, utilize o **NOT IN**:

```
UPDATE pessoas 
SET implante = false
WHERE pessoas.prontuario NOT IN (SELECT saida.prontuario
                                 FROM saida 
                                 WHERE saida.mes LIKE (date_part('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE) || '%'))
```

Comment: Positivo Heitor, grato. Mas preciso que além de registrar true nos prontuários dentro da condição, registrar, também, false para os prontuários fora da condição.

Comment: Para atualizar com o false, e só utilizar o NOT IN (o que não estiver dentro do in), editei a resposta com o exemplo.